# Differential Equation related problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{{{d^2}x}}{{d{y^2}}} =$

(A) ${\left( {\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}}} \right)^{ - 1}}$

(B) $ - {\left( {\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}}} \right)^{ - 1}}{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)^{ - 3}}$

(C) $\left( {\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}}} \right){\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)^{ - 2}}$

(D) $ - \left( {\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}}} \right){\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)^{ - 3}}$

The correct answer is (D) viz. $ - \left( {\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}}} \right){\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)^{ - 3}}$

My approach is as follow

$\frac{{{d^2}x}}{{d{y^2}}} = \frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dy}}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dy}}\frac{1}{{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}} =  - \frac{{\frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}}{{{{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}^2}}}$

How I will proceed with the numerator part ${\frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)=\left(\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)\right)\frac{dx}{dy}=\left(\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)\right)\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$

$$\frac{{{d^2}x}}{{d{y^2}}} = \frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dy}}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dy}}\frac{1}{{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}} =  - \frac{{\frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}}{{{{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}^2}}}=- \frac{\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}}{{{{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}^2}}}=-\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3}$$

Comment: Hi Jean ! Long time no speak. Cheers :-)

Comment: It is important to mention that this identity holds for non-constant explicit functions $y=f(x)$ which have inverse in the specified domain and range.

Answer (score 1):

Let's unpack this to avoid abuse of notation.

You have some twice differentiable function $y=f(x)$ and its (local) inverse function $x=g(y)$. You want to express the second derivative of $g$ in terms of derivatives of $f$. Using the usual $x=g(f(x))$ with the chain rule gives
$$
1=g'(f(x))f'(x).
$$
Applying product and chain rule to that results in
$$
0=g''(f(x))f'(x)^2+g'(f(x))f''(x).
$$
Now apply the first order identity to eliminate $g'$ to find
$$
g''(f(x))=-\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^3}.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to look at this seemingly more "general" identity as asked by the OP.